# In email coming from salesforce what is X-SFDC-EmailCategory

Tags: case, emailmessage

I would like to know what this statement means. 
X-SFDC-EmailCategory: caseCommentNotification

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details in below-mentioned links.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205334&type=1

> Within the email header content, search for the "X-SFDC-LK" &
>   "X-SFDC-User" values
>
> The values included for these entries will identify the Organization
>   ID (X-SFDC-LK) and the User ID (X-SFDC-User) in which these emails
>   originated.
>
> Other useful information can be found in the headers of email from
>   salesforce such as the
>
> > "X-SFDC-EntityId" which in the case of Workflow would show the id of
> >     the workflow that triggered the email.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000188046&type=1

> ```
> Subject: test email
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
>   boundary="----=_Part_31262_376962461.1389046146932"
> X-SFDC-ORGTYPE: FREE
> X-SFDC-LK: 00D50000000IQwR
> X-SFDC-User: 00550000001Zf61
> X-Sender: postmaster@salesforce.com
> X-mail_abuse_inquiries: http://www.salesforce.com/company/abuse.jsp
> X-SFDC-TLS-NoRelay: 1
> X-SFDC-EmailCategory: emailAuthorEmail
> X-SFDC-EntityId: 000000000000000
> X-SFDC-Binding: 1WrIRBV94myi25uC
> X-pstn-neptune: 0/0/0.00/0
> X-pstn-levels: (S:49.31071/99.90000 CV:99.9000 FC:95.5390 LC:95.5390 R:95.9108 P:95.9108 M:97.0282 C:98.6951 )
> X-pstn-dkim: 0 skipped:not-enabled
> X-pstn-cm-addresses: from <wbamann@salesforce.com> (approved)
> X-pstn-settings: 3 (1.0000:0.0005) s cv gt4 gt3 GT2 gt1 p
> X-pstn-addresses: from <wbamann@salesforce.com> forward (org good) [db-null]
> X-pstn-nxpr: disp=neutral, envrcpt=wbamann@salesforce.com
> X-pstn-nxp: bodyHash=fc046c0b5e85cebaf6cfb21b69bd44573fc1d653, 
> headerHash=479949543731a27d88943ececf83136227a00a56, keyName=4,
> rcptHash=d2bdf7edb11a749779317b57aa4594a2c9712fa7,
> sourceip=204.14.232.79, version=1
>
> ------=_Part_31262_376962461.1389046146932
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> test email
>
> THIS IS A TEST
>
> _____________________________________________________________________
> Powered by salesforce.com
> http://www.salesforce.com/
>
> ------=_Part_31262_376962461.1389046146932
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
>
> You can see the Fields that will identify the type of organization sent the Email as well as the ID and the User.
> ```

---

> ```
> X-SFDC-ORGTYPE: FREE X-SFDC-LK: 00D50000000IQwR X-SFDC-User: 00550000001Zf61h
>
>
> NOTE The field X-SFDC-ORGTYPE will only display from Emails sent out of "Free' or "Trial" Orgs. This will not display when sent from
>  any other environment.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is this is either sending because of [Support Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_supportrules.htm&type=5) (aka Case Settings) or the emails attached to the Case Assignment rules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).